# How can I mix SVG and HTML into a page?

Tags: firefox, xhtml, html, svg

I've been using the [jQuery.svg plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) to do some SVG rendering and it works perfectly but I also want to have the server render some SVG into the page and I can't get that to work. How do I add some SVG like below into the page so that Firefox will render it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="map editable" id="map_1"><svg height="600" version="1.1" width="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><image height="600" href="/system/graphics/1/original/floor-plan-large.gif" width="500" x="0" y="0" /><circle cx="300" cy="580" fill="red" r="5" stroke-width="2" stroke="red" /><circle cx="300" cy="400" fill="red" r="5" stroke-width="2" stroke="red" /><circle cx="260" cy="400" fill="red" r="5" stroke-width="2" stroke="red" /><circle cx="260" cy="340" fill="red" r="5" stroke-width="2" stroke="red" /><circle cx="140" cy="340" fill="red" r="5" stroke-width="2" stroke="red" /><polyline fill="none" points="300,580 300,400 260,400 260,340 140,340" stroke-width="3" stroke="blue" /></svg></div>

    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300px" height="200px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="150px" cy="100px" r="50px" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5px"/>
    </svg>


    <svg:svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300px" height="200px">
      <svg:circle cx="150px" cy="100px" r="50px" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5px"/>
    </svg:svg>

    </body>
</html>
```

Do I need a meta tag saying that there is SVG content in the page or define the SVG namespace somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) (SVG in HTML introduction @ Mozilla Developer Center).

An inline SVG example [can be seen here](http://jwatt.org/svg/demos/xhtml-with-inline-svg.xhtml).

Comment: I look a look at those links and added the xmlns references that were missing and it still isn't working. I updated the question with a full html page that isn't working, what am I missing?

Comment: What headers is your webserver using? See this page (unfortunately only in google cache: http://74.125.77.132/search?q=cache:12YX1EBBv8cJ:wiki.svg.org/Inline_SVG+xhtml+svg+inline+headers&cd=1&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=be)

Comment: Make sure the webserver serves this as `application/xhtml+xml`.

Comment: thanks Chris, it was the headers that was preventing it from working

Answer (score 0):

What is your doctype? Make sure it is the same as the example, i.e. XHTML, not HTML 4.01 TRANSITIONAL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
          PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of [building inline SVGs dynamically with JavaScript](http://bit.ly/jmWtFF).

Answer (score 0):

In 2020, using `SVG` in html or xhtml is now possible in all browsers.

Example of HTML / SVG(2.0) code that I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<head> <title>SVG within XHTML Demo</title> </head>
<body>
  <p>
    <b>Electricity Plan</b>
  </p>
  <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='2.0' width='8000px' height='6000px'>
    <defs>
      <g id="prise">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20" y2="0" stroke="blue"/>
        <line x1="20" y1="-15" x2="20" y2="15" stroke="blue"/>
        <path d="m40,-20 a20,20 0 0,0 0,40" fill="none" stroke="blue"/>
        <line x1="40" y1="-20" x2="40" y2="-28" stroke="blue"/>
        <line x1="40" y1="20" x2="40" y2="28" stroke="blue"/>
      </g>
    </defs>
    <line x1='100' y1='50' x2='140' y2='50' stroke='blue'/>
    <use href='#prise' x='140' y='50'/>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```